# How to know the APIs called by Zabbix dashboard?

Tags: zabbix

I am installed zabbix on localhost. I am login and view zabbix monitoring dashboard http://localhost/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.view&ddreset=1
I see many svg graph chart. I checked network tab on chrome developer tool and find in the zabbix frontend source code to find the APIs. That get data for generate the svg graph chart. However, I can't find the APIs called by dashboard svg graph chart.

Please help me,
How to check the APIs called by svg graph on dashboard?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

To see API calls, you can use the [Debug mode](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_interface/debug_mode), which has to be enabled on a per-user basis. When you activate it inside a Dashboard, each widget switches to a debug view.

Please note that while most widgets are completely switched to debug view, the chart ones needs scrolling in order to see the debug part. Example screenshot for [classic charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uezfL.png) and [new charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzJnr.png).

Comment: Thanks Iron Bishop, Can you share with me The dashboard.view (http://localhost/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=dashboard.view&ddreset=1) using the server gender or client gender? Thank you so much,

Comment: Hi Iron Bishop, When I view with debug mode on the screen action dashboard.view. I seen the APIs & SQL for the Problem widget. But I can't see the APIs and SQL for the graph chart. How to know the APIs for the action widget.svggraph.view? you can see the image http://vng.edu.vn/sites/default/files/field/image/dashboard_view.png . Please help me, Thank you so much.

Comment: You need to scroll down in order to see the debug view in the chart widget. See the screnshot: https://i.imgur.com/I8qhwwX.png

Comment: Thank you, Today morning I check html element and see the debug element with display: none. So, I change it to display: block and I can see it.

Comment: Now I want to create a new API. I create a CTestApi.php file in the D:\xampp\htdocs\zabbix\include\classes\api\services\CTestApi.php and I create a `function public static function TestApi() {
        return self::getApi('testapi');
    }
}` I am using postman to test the API. http://localhost/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php with the param `{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "testapi.get",
    "params": {
        "output": "extend"
    },
    "auth": "891692ab3070e64f9d3439278a5bbcb8",
    "id": 1
}` Could you share for me how to add new APIs into zabbix frontend?

Comment: This is the result when call the API above. `{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32602,
        "message": "Invalid params.",
        "data": "Incorrect API \"testapi\"."
    },
    "id": 1
}`

Comment: That's not how you extend the API. The main Class is zabbix/frontends/php/include/classes/api/API.php , but it's not necessary to extend the API in order to use it to create SVG graphs.

Comment: Thanks Iron Bishop, Could you tell me how to extend API? How to debug to the API? example I want to debug to method get of the Graph (D:\xampp\htdocs\zabbix\include\classes\api\services\CGraph.php). I am using PHPStorm and tried with xdebug and zend-debug. However, when I call the get APIs it not run to debbug. Please help me, Thank you so much.

Comment: Since the API already covers almost every aspect of Zabbix, which feature you need to add?

Comment: Thanks Iron Bishop, Zabbix have a lot APIs. I had finished configuration to debug on zabbix APIs. Now, I am trying to create a new smoke get API example. I can't find any document about create new API for zabbix frontend. Could you help me? Thank you so much.